# Как обновить роли у пользователя?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Не могу найти, как обновить роли у пользователя? `Users` - содержит Id пользователя. `Role` - id ролей которые нужны.
Таблица с ролями стандартная indentity 2.0: `AspNetUserRoles` с полями `UserId` и `RoleId`.

Вот попытки:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Roles(string Users, string Role)
{
    var roledb = db.Roles.Find(Users);

    db.Entry(roledb).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");

    return View();
}
```

Comment: А почему Вы не пользуетесь RoleManager/UserManager?

Comment: В каком виде "Users - содержит Id " если у вас `string Users` , думаю стоит заменить `find` на `where`  с целью понимания того что мы ищем и по какому полю?

Answer (score 1):

ваш код пытается найти пользователя с именем Users в таблице Roles. 
потом он, ***не меняя найденную запись***, помечает ее как измененную и сохраняет 
в БД. Полагаю, стоит установить новую роль пользователю перед сохранением. Код прилагать не буду, не знаю структуры БД.

Comment: Это я понимаю. Но данный код не находит запись, думал может ошибся в db.Roles.Find(Users) ? хотя в таблице строка с таким UserId точно есть.

Answer (score 1):

раз уж речь идет об [asp.net-identity-2](/questions/tagged/asp.net-identity-2) то почему бы не воспользоваться готовым функционалом [UserManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn468199%28v=vs.111%29.aspx):

- [AddToRoleAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn468058%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)
- [RemoveFromRoleAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn468066%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Недавно столкнулся с **Asp Net Identity 2.0** в рабочем проекте, так что добавлю правильный ответ. В пакете Microsoft.AspNet.Identity менеджер ролей организован аналогично менеджеру пользователей. Для вас уже подготовлены стандартные сущности которые можно использовать и расширять при необходимости:

Есть менеджер = `RoleManager<IdentityRole>`

Есть роли которыми он управляет = `IdentityRole`

Есть хранилище = `RoleStore<IdentityRole>`

Контекст EF, используемый хранилищем = `ApplicationDbContext`

Я немного упростил код, унаследовался от RoleManager и вот что получилось:

```
 public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> store) : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new
                RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationContext>()));
    }
}
```

Т.к. вся инфраструктура Identity представлена как OWIN Middleware, вам необходимо предоставить фабрику, создающую ваш менеджер ролей. Метод Create как раз и выступает в роли данной фабрики. Укажем его в OWIN-инициализаторе (методе Startup.ConfigureAuth())

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

Теперь в любом контроллере мы можем получить уже инициализированный `RoleMananger` через OwinContext

```
var roleManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
```